# debugging app at multiple devices at the same time - is it possible?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, usb-debugging

Is it possible to use one computer to debug two or more devices at the same time via USB? (App uses Bluetooth, so the ability not to share application through Google Drive after every fix would be brilliant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a VM with a Linux distro, then run Android Studio from the host OS and another Android Studio from the guest OS.